# Global Injectivity Of A Multi Variable Function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, jacobian

Let $f:A\subseteq \Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ be differentiable and $Df(x)$ denote the Jacobian of $f$ at $x$.

If, $$Df(x)\neq 0,\;\;\;\forall x\in \Bbb R^n-------(*)$$

Then by Inverse Function Theorem we can conclude that, $\forall x \in \Bbb R^n \;\;\exists $ a neighborhood of $x$ in which $f$ is invertible, also $f$ is injective therein.

My question is- Does $(*)\implies$ $f$ is injective on $A$?

In general how do we check whether $f$ is injective or surjective on $A$
? Are we supposed to simply use the definitions of injectivity and surjectivity or can we make use of the values of Jacobian to conclude something?

Comment: Consider $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x^2$. This is locally injective, but clearly not globally injective.

Comment: @YousufSoliman: your $f $ is not locally injective at zero.

Comment: Ahh, my bad.... I was thinking too quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexamples are trivial if $A $ is not connected.

Let $n=2$, $$A=\{(x,y):\  xy\ne0\}, $$ and $f (x,y)=(x^2,y^2)$. The Jacobian is $$Df (x,y)=\det\begin{bmatrix}2x&0\\0&2y\end{bmatrix}=4xy. $$ The conditions on $A $ guarantee that $Df\ne0$; and $f (1,1)=f (-1,1) $.

When $A $ is connected, the result is true for $n=1$.

For $n\geq2$, the situation is [likely more subtle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47612/how-to-globalize-the-inverse-function-theorem?rq=1).

Comment: That was a really nice and a simple example. Thank You.